# Fazendo JSON PHP

Tags: php, json

Pessoal estou precisando criar um JSON, porém não estou conseguindo, olhe meu código abaixo:

```
$sqlCelula = "SELECT * from tbl_CELULAS WHERE COD_IDENT_IGREJ = 'igj";

$celulaVars = array();
$celulaVars[':igj'] = $suc->getCOD_IDENT_IGREJ();

$celulas = $conexao->fetch($sqlCelula, $celulaVars);

$json = array();

if ($celulas) {

    foreach ($celulas as $celula) {
        $cel = array();

        $cel->TXT_ENDER_CEPXX = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CEPXX;
        $cel->SGL_ENDER_ESTAD = $celula->SGL_ENDER_ESTAD;
        $cel->TXT_ENDER_CIDAD = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CIDAD;
        $cel->TXT_ENDER_BAIRR = $celula->TXT_ENDER_BAIRR;
        $cel->TXT_ENDER_LOGRA = $celula->TXT_ENDER_LOGRA;
        $cel->TXT_ENDER_NUMER = $celula->TXT_ENDER_NUMER;

        $json->CELULAS = $cel;
    }
}

$json_encode = json_encode($json);
```

Neste eu pesquiso no banco, com resultado faço o `foreach` para passear sobre o resultado, e vou pegando um por um dos dados que quero, no final pego tudo isto e coloco dentro do `array` que criei, e depois dou `json_encode`. O resultado disto está saindo `[]`.

Comment: 1° você esta criando um array cell a cada indice percorrido do loop, segundo você não recebe valor assim, você pode utilizar algo como $array['chaveDoArray'] = valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente substituir esse seu trecho de código:

```
foreach ($celulas as $celula) {
    $cel = array();

    $cel->TXT_ENDER_CEPXX = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CEPXX;
    $cel->SGL_ENDER_ESTAD = $celula->SGL_ENDER_ESTAD;
    $cel->TXT_ENDER_CIDAD = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CIDAD;
    $cel->TXT_ENDER_BAIRR = $celula->TXT_ENDER_BAIRR;
    $cel->TXT_ENDER_LOGRA = $celula->TXT_ENDER_LOGRA;
    $cel->TXT_ENDER_NUMER = $celula->TXT_ENDER_NUMER;

    $json->CELULAS = $cel;
}
```

Por este:

```
foreach ($celulas as $celula) {
    $cel = array();

    $cel['TXT_ENDER_CEPXX'] = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CEPXX;
    $cel['SGL_ENDER_ESTAD'] = $celula->SGL_ENDER_ESTAD;
    $cel['TXT_ENDER_CIDAD'] = $celula->TXT_ENDER_CIDAD;
    $cel['TXT_ENDER_BAIRR'] = $celula->TXT_ENDER_BAIRR;
    $cel['TXT_ENDER_LOGRA'] = $celula->TXT_ENDER_LOGRA;
    $cel['TXT_ENDER_NUMER'] = $celula->TXT_ENDER_NUMER;

    $json['CELULAS'] = $cel;
}
```

Comment: Continua dando vazio do mesmo jeito.